# Multiuser in excel 2010

Tags: excel, sharing, multi-user

I am new to this stackoverflow and i can say that its a very interesting and resourceful website.

I need to share a workbook on a network and as you already know the workbook must not contain any table or XML maps but i prefer to use a table because it is an expandable range. Information are extracted from this table via formulas.

Is there any work around possible to share the workbook with the table included?
I do not want to use formula for an expandable range in order to maximize the efficiency of the workbook because there are already lots of formula in the workbook.

Besides what is the maximum number of users that can access the workbook at the same time, with each user having access to only one worksheet

Thanking you in advance for your precious help.

Best Regards

Jack

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx) has:

[image: SO21645414 example]

Note first and last entries in the image.

And that it was the first hit to the Google query `Excel 2010 spec`

so please see also the first bullet point [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).